# Has anyone made the admin interface for orders better for multi address orders?

Tags: admin, shipping-address

We have a client doing a lot of order management in Magento, and trying to multi address checkout is annoying. Well, for the admin and Magento it doesn't exist. You have to keep placing new orders. This means asking for credit card information over and over again.

I would think that creating a multi address admin checkout would probably be a huge undertaking and probably not recommended. I am also looking into possibly using the Authorize.net CIM module for saved credit cards to get over the asking of information over and over again. However, I am just checking to see if there  is anything I am missing or if there are any extensions out there to make this process more streamlined?

Comment: Why not just use multiaddress checkout on the front-end? Or just create the single order and ship/fulfill to separate addresses?

Comment: because they want to be able to track their CSR's through the admin orders

Answer (score 2):

I have a client with exactly the same issue. What we're doing at the moment is creating the order from the frontend, and displaying a cash payment option for the admin user only. Then the payment is taken manually via MOTO. If you're looking for a step up on this, I would suggest looking at enabling MOTO payments from the frontend for this user ONLY.

I spent a long time trying to find what you're looking for, and we discussed developing something ourselves, but in the end, as the feature already existed in the frontend, that's the way we opted for.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well. Does your admin user just log in with their username in the front that is associated to a specific admin group and then just fills in the customers billing info and what not?

Comment: Hi Dan. Yeah, that's exactly how it works. Seems to work pretty well too. Cheers